# Create a "Are you older than 18?" home page?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm creating an adult website and I'm trying to create a homepage that will ask my viewers if they want to see adult content.

More or less something like this:

"Are you 18 years old and are you willing to see adult content?"

Yes/No button.

Are there any extensions that I can use to create this type of stuff ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of extensions in Joomla Extensions Directory that might do what you want - jQuery Content Disclaimer (free), ProAge Check (paid).  I haven't used them but they might be worth a try.

Comment: jQuery Content Disclaimer is great, not exactly what I was searching for but I think it'll do just fine. Thank you a lot !